# css background-color in custom shape

Tags: css, background-color

I want to make background like in photo, but without image. I want with only "background-color" like background in "About us" link

[image]

Comment: Sounds great. What have you tried?

Comment: like http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pyOxyV/ ? if yes, this was an answer to a question here among many duplicates actually, a little search on SO should do it :)

Comment: Why some one had made Down Vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using CSS `transform:` with value `skew()`;

```css
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 45px;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;

}


li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 24px;
    transform: skew(20deg); /* To Achieve the Slanted border */
    margin-right: -3px;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transform: skew(-20deg); /* To straighten up the text */
}
```

```html
<ul>

     <li><a href"#">About</a></li>
    
    
</ul>
```

[Click here for a full tutorial on how you can do that.](http://webdesignsharepoint.com/create-slanted-navigation-tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a parallellogram or rhombus. To do this you can use `transform: skew`

```css
#about {
 width: 120px;
 height: 20px;
 -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
      -o-transform: skew(20deg);
 background: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">About us</div>
```